# How do I store an arraylist into internal storage?

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, internal-storage, android-internal-storage

I want to create an ArrayList, which then gets stored into the phone's internal storage. I also want to retrieve that ArrayList again. Another thing I want to do is put ArrayLists into that ArrayList. Does anyone know how to do that? I am using Kotlin to code.

Comment: you should use Room and type convertors

Answer (score 0):

To me this seems like a regular serialization problem. You can either use [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite) (with [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) as others suggested) or something similar to store the data, or you can just serialize the objects using [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers).